# How to concatenate all entries returned by a joined subquery (related to the main table id) into a single combined column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a main driver table called `Employee` with the following data and columns:

```
 EMPLOYEE_ID    EMPLOYEE_NAME      EMPLOYEE_CAR     EMPLOYEE_AGE
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
     1          Mike               Camry                35          
     2          Mark               Civic                33
     3          Helen              Beetle               25
```

And I have another table called `Employee_Feedback` with the following data and columns:

```
 EMPLOYEE_FEEDBACK_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID       FEEDBACK_COMMENT_TX
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
        1                      1              Very Good
        2                      1              Average
        3                      1              Phenomenal
        4                      2              Okay
        5                      2              NO Comment
        6                      3              Excellent
        7                      3              Hilarious
```

With the data from the `Employee` and `Employee_Feedback` tables, I want my query to be able to return all of the rows in Employee and also to concatenate all of the 'related' employee feedback_comments from `Employee_feedback` into a  single column per employee. It would look like this:

```
 EMPLOYEE_NAME    EMPLOYEE_CAR     EMPLOYEE_AGE   Comments
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Mike             Camry              35           Very Good Average Phenomenal
 Mark             Civic              33           Okay No Comment 
 Helen            Beetle             25           Excellent Hilarious
```

What would be a good query to do this? I've tried the following with no success:

```
select employee_name
     , employee_car
     , employee_age
     , listagg(feedback_comment_Tx, ' ') within group (order by e.employee_id)
  from employee e
  join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id;
```

Am I missing a minor detail? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` clause at the end :

```
group by employee_name, employee_car, employee_age
```

**Edit :** including your filters in the comment, you may try the following :

```
select employee_name
     , employee_car
     , employee_age
     , listagg(feedback_comment_Tx, ' ') within group (order by e.employee_id)
  from employee e
  join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id
 where nvl(initcap(feedback_comment_Tx),'No Comment') != 'No Comment'
 group by employee_name, employee_car, employee_age;
```

Comment: Thanks. Question: If i wanted to add a FILTERING clause that only brings in comments that are NOT null / blank or 'No Comment', how would I be able to rewrite my query to do this?

Comment: @JohnWick you're welcome. Then, You need to add a `where` clause after `join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id where ...` as what do you want to filter. `group by ` still should stay at the very end(after `where` clause in this case).

Comment: Thank you, you are always super helpful!

Comment: @JohnWick Thank you, too dear friend :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select employee_name
     , employee_car
     , employee_age
     , listagg(feedback_comment_Tx, ' ') within group (order by ef.EMPLOYEE_FEEDBACK_ID)
  from employee e
  join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id
  group by e.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add `group by e.employee_id` at the end of query like that

```
select employee_name
 , employee_car
 , employee_age
 , listagg(feedback_comment_Tx, ' ') within group (order by e.employee_id) 
   from employee e join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id 
    group by e.employee_id
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i wanted to add a FILTERING clause that only brings in comments that are NOT null / blank or 'No Comment', how would I be able to rewrite my query to do this?

Comment: `select employee_name
 , employee_car
 , employee_age
 , listagg(feedback_comment_Tx, ' ') within group (order by e.employee_id) 
   from employee e join employee_feedback ef ON ef.employee_id = e.employee_id and ef. feedback_comment_Tx IS NOT NULL 
    group by e.employee_id`